# I am getting Erroe while run a web page how to solve this error Server Error in '/'

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am getting Error while run a web page, how to solve this error

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'FrontTeam1.Pages.Front.WebForm1'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/Master/FrontTeam.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="FrontTeam1.Pages.Front.WebForm1" %>
Line 2:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
Line 3:  </asp:Content>



Source File:  /Pages/Front/WebForm1.aspx    Line:  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the class: FrontTeam1.Pages.Front.WebForm1

Make sure it's in the correct location